# Django dumpdata slow after delete all records in table

Tags: python-3.x, django

I cleared a table using

```
RulesUsed.objects.all().delete()
```

There were about 35,000 records in the table (out of a total database of 45,000 records in all tables).

```
python manage.py dumpdata --exclude auth.permission --exclude contenttypes > db_input.json
```

dumpdata went from about 17 **seconds** before delete to more than **19 minutes** after.

I have tried rebuilding the container and loading the data with json file from dumpdata -- so there is no data in the (now) empty table. dumpdata time on the new database is the same -- 19 **minutes**.

```
python manage.py loaddata --ignorenonexistent /scripts/db_input.json
```

I feel I have misunderstood something and there is some relation slowing things down.

I tried clearing from command line with same result of 19 minutes;

```
python manage.py shell
from appname.models import RulesUsed
RulesUsed.objects.all().delete()
```

The table is a child of another, the model is;

```
class RulesUsed(models.Model):

    hs_input = models.ForeignKey(
        hs_input,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='rules_used'
        )

    Rule_Type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Rule = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Value = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    Rule_Comment = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
            ordering = ['hs_input','Rule_Type','Rule']

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.hs_input} : {self.Rule_Type} : {self.Rule} : {self.Value}'

    def as_dict(self):
        return {'id': self.hs_input,
                'Rule type' : self.Rule_Type,
                'Rule' :  self.Rule,
                'Value' :  self.Value,
                'Rule comment' :  self.Rule_Comment
        }
```

The database is Postgres. Python 3.8. Django 2.2.5. Running in Docker containers.

Comment: I updated to Python 3.9 and Django 3.0.3 -- the time went up slightly.

Comment: In PostgreSQL, try a `VACUUM FULL VERBOSE appname_rulesused`, then give it a whirl again? That will clear out all dead tuples from the database.

Comment: thanks. unfortunately did not help. the output of the command was `INFO:  "appname_rulesused": found 0 removable, 0 nonremovable row versions in 0 pages` `DETAIL:  0 dead row versions cannot be removed yet.`

Comment: I do not have an answer, but I have an observation; In the past I have simply redirected the output to standard out using redirect (>). Using `--format=yaml` was 'fast' like before (less than 13 seconds). Using  `--format=json` was slow. *NOT* redirecting to std out but using `--output myfilename` was just as fast for yaml but ALSO FAST for json! whatever the issue is it is to do with redirecting json to std out.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
--output OUTPUT, -o OUTPUT¶
```

Specifies a file to write the serialized data to. By default, the data goes to standard output.

```
root@812e9c4b1e07:/estimate# time python manage.py dumpdata --exclude auth.permission --exclude contenttypes --format=yaml --output  db_20201201_1730.yaml
DEBUG:asyncio:Using selector: EpollSelector
[...........................................................................]

real    0m13.927s
user    0m12.194s
sys 0m0.542s
root@812e9c4b1e07:/estimate# time python manage.py dumpdata --exclude auth.permission --exclude contenttypes --format=json --output  db_20201201_1730.json
DEBUG:asyncio:Using selector: EpollSelector
[...........................................................................]

real    0m7.636s
user    0m5.375s
sys 0m0.385s
root@812e9c4b1e07:/estimate# time python manage.py dumpdata --exclude auth.permission --exclude contenttypes --format=json > db_20201201_1745.json
DEBUG:asyncio:Using selector: EpollSelector

real    21m46.728s
user    0m59.013s
sys 1m13.793s
root@812e9c4b1e07:/estimate#
```